# Git: push a different changeset to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, changeset

I want to push a previous version of my repository. How can I push to heroku a previous changeset?

something like:

> git push heroku 07226c49428354b09349ec45078122ce7cd410c8

thanks!

**EDIT: Some trials**

git branch -a produces

```
master
remotes/heroku/master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

Trying something like

```
git push heroku 07226c49428354b09349ec45078122ce7cd410c8:master
```

give me:

```
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I am guessing this is because my current heroku deployment is the HEAD, and since I want to deploy a previous changeset, git throws up an error. So I re-create the new heroku stack (delete the current heroku, delete its reference, and create a new heroku cedar stack), and try pushing the particular changeset again. This time, on an empty heroku deployment I get:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master The
>   destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
>   begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the
>   source ref. error: failed to push some refs to
>   'git@heroku.com:empty-waterfall-8460.git'

Any ideas how to push a different changeset without any of these problems? Or do I have to create a branch everytime starting at a particular changeset, re-create heroku stack and push that branch?

Answer (score 0):

```
git push heroku 07226c49428354b09349ec45078122ce7cd410c8:master
```

You might want to create a branch or tag for this commit, for future reference.

EDIT: I think it should be:

```
git push -f heroku 07226c49428354b09349ec45078122ce7cd410c8:master
```

which addresses the first error. I'm not sure what's happening after you recreated the stack.

Comment: for some reason, I am getting the following error:

The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:furious-frost-6040.git'
any idea why?

Comment: @Newton, post the output of `git branch -a` in your question.